# How do I allow a "SPACE" character in an AutoComplete JavaFX uneditable ComboBox?

Tags: combobox, autocomplete, javafx-8

When I type a SPACE character in an AutoComplete ComboBox, I can get the space character to be accepted except the addEventFilter code I'm using to manage it multiplies and inserts a space for each character previously typed prior to the space. You can see a screen shot example below where 3 spaces were added after the 3 characters (ive), then 4 spaces added after I include an additional charater (t), each after typing a single SPACE, and the spaces only appear after I type the next character (e.g. 'm').

[image: Adds 3 spaces then adds 4 after next character is typed]

I did try this with the ContolsFX AutoComplete, but it cannot handle the uneditable ComboBox - and couldn't find anything to the contrary. In the online cases I research, it was recommended to use the ComboBox's popup skin - addEventFilter to manage the SPACE character event. In nearly all the cases it was to consume() and prevent the space from selection and closing. I did not find anything that strictly allowed the space to be entered. I've tried adding the SPACE in code prior to and after this Event Code but the addEventFilter event.consume() will remove it. The SPACE character will only appear if I manage its addition within the addEventFilter method. I've tried different events such as KeyEvent.ANY, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, and KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASE and read the documentation on the KeyEvent, but only KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED seems to allow the SPACE character, it just multiplies the number of spaces, and doesn't insert until the next text character.

```
ComboBoxListViewSkin cbSkin = cbSkin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin(cmb);
```

// cmb is the ComboBox

```
    cbSkin.getPopupContent().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (event) -> {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE){
            filter += " ";
            event.consume();}
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. The event code needed to be a part of the ComboBoxAutoComplete constructor and not part of the onKeyPressed event.

```
private ComboBoxListViewSkin cbSkin;

public ComboBoxAutoComplete(ComboBox<T> cmb) {
    this.cmb = cmb;
    cbSkin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin(cmb);
    originalItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(cmb.getItems());
    cmb.setOnKeyPressed(this::handleOnKeyPressed);
    cmb.setOnHidden(this::handleOnHiding);
    cmb.setSkin(cbSkin);
    cbSkin.getPopupContent().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (event) -> {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE){
            filter += " ";
            event.consume();}
    });
}
```

[image: addFilterEvent_in_Constructor]